# Signal handling IN critical section

Tags: c, signals, critical-section, reentrancy

**Practice** :

From my understanding, one may want to allow critical sections of code to run without interruption.

one may do so by blocking interruption such as standard signals.

**The Conflict :**

How will i be able to handle faults/standard signals that occurs from a critical section code.
A classic example i can think of, is a failure to allocate memory.
Or even better, failure to free memory due to invalid address.
Memory operations from the "alloc/free" section from my understand do belong to the critical section part.

**What have i tried :**

I did try to search around, as well as study the subject of signals and reentrancy,
However i stumbled upon this conflict.

Some input will be great, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Allocating memory has *nothing* to do with signals. A signal is something you cause by Ctrl-C, or by a dying child.

Comment: Allocate the memory outside the critical section. Only update the pointer inside the critical section.

Comment: or by memory fault? for example.

Comment: Well, don't make "memory faults" (I have no idea what that is) in your critical section then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX signals, return codes and exceptions are different things.

> critical sections of code to run without interruption

To be precise, a critical section is a block of code guarded by mutex locks. That is, only one thread can enter a critical section at a time.

> How will i be able to handle faults/standard signals that occurs from a critical section code. A classic example i can think of, is a failure to allocate memory.

On failure `malloc` returns `NULL`, no signals are involved here.

> Or even better, failure to free memory due to invalid address.

This type of error cannot be handled by the code. It is a programming error that must be discovered as early as possible and fixed. One of the best tools for discovering this type of errors is [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Because when you receive `SIGSEGV`, `SIGBUS`, `SIGILL` or `SIGFPE` signal, the state of your process address space is indeterminate, the code might have corrupted all process memory by the time `SIGSEGV` was generated, so there is no good way to recover the correct state of your program after this signal has been received.

Comment: Thank you, The goal i was aiming towards when handling standard signals was to actually throw a memory dump core into a stream, Not to recover from it, Obviously if a software is heading towards a crash, You should let it crash.

Comment: @Illasera These signals by default cause core dump, see [`man signal(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). You may need to enable core dumps in you `.bash_profile` with `ulimit -c unlimited`. See [`man core(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) for more details. Alternatively enable core files programmatically by using `setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, ...)` and `prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 1, 0, 0, 0)`.

Comment: If i recall correctly while checking it once, as well as re-checking it now, It does not cover stack backtracing as well as used file descriptors at the point of crash, nor other data that is populated in procfs, or other queries i may wish to perform on my own accord Now the question is, Based on your main answer, If getting such data DURING a crash is even valid. (I did not point it our earlier, Sorry about that.)

Comment: @Illasera File descriptors are maintained by the kernel, so they cannot be corrupted by a user-space process. Stack can well be corrupted though.

Comment: @Illasera Basically, your crash handler may like to spawn `gdb` to get the stack trace and `lsof` to get file descriptors and once these finish terminate the process. This should be done by separate processes to reduce the possibility of your process crashing once again while collecting post-mortem data about itself.